# Conditional javascript generation based on Typescript function generic type parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Providing I have got an object that consists of keys and true/false value that switch on or off logging and a log function

```js
const LoggedKeys = {
  logged: true,
  ignored: false,
}
function log(key, msg) {
  if(LoggedKeys[key]) console.log(msg);
}
log('logged', "This should be logged")
log('ignored', "That should not do anything")
```

is it possible to write TypeScript version that for keys, whose type was false would not generate function call or generate empty function during compilation? (just to save performance drawback of many calls to log function where LoggedKey is false anyway)

Something like:

```js
interface LoggedKeys {
  logged: true,
  ignored: false,
}
type MyLogFunction<T keyof LoggedKeys> = LoggedKeys[T] extends true? (msg) => void: never
// I have no idea how it would look like 
// and usage could look like
log<logged>("That would generate proper log function")
log<ignored>("That would be erased during compilation or generate fake empty function during compilation")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever JavaScript syntax exists in the TypeScript will also exist in the emitted JavaScript. So this

```
log<logged>("That would generate proper log function")
log<ignored>("That would be erased during compilation or generate fake empty function during compilation")
```

will *necessarily* result in JavaScript of

```
log("That would generate proper log function")
log("That would be erased during compilation or generate fake empty function during compilation")
```

There's no way, using standard TypeScript, for any alternative. You could think of the compilation process as doing *one* thing, primarily; removing the TypeScript syntax so that what remains is valid JavaScript. No additional dynamic logic occurs, really (except for a couple weird things like enums, which also exist in emitted code).

You will have to change the `log` function to implement the desired logic in JavaScript, which probably requires passing another argument instead of a generic argument.